# Plotly.js Create stacked and grouped bar chart

Tags: javascript, plotly, plotly.js

How to create barchart on **Plotly.js** with grouped and stacked bars? I need structure like that:
[Barchart with stacked and grouped charts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yeEYR.png)

Comment: I'd suggest reading the [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page and improving your question. There's no description here of what specific problem you might be facing so you're unlikely to get anything beyond linking to the [Plotly stacked bar chart help page](https://plot.ly/javascript/bar-charts/#stacked-bar-chart)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is possible to create a grouped-and-stacked bar chart in Plotly.js by creating each group as a subplot. It's not as simple as setting a top-level feature like 'barmode': 'stacked+grouped' but because it's more elemental it offers more options.

See https://community.plot.ly/t/combination-of-grouped-and-stacked-bar-chart/2154

Here each subplot references a shared common yaxis and its own xaxis. Each xaxis gets a "domain" which here means a portion of the overall bottom axis width. Here the first group gets [0.0, 0.33], the second [0.34, 0.66] and the third [0.67, 1.0]

[image]

```
   Plotly.newPlot(
  "myDiv",
  [
    {
      x: ["A", "B", "C"],
      y: [0.3, 0.35, 0.4],
      type: "bar",
      name: "series 1a", 
      xaxis: 'x1',
      barmode: 'stack', 
      marker: {color: '#448'}
    },
    {
      x: ["A", "B", "C"],
      y: [0.6, 0.50, 0.40],
      type: "bar",
      name: "series 1b", 
      xaxis: 'x1',
      barmode: 'stack', marker: {color: '#88C'}
    },
    {
      x: ["A", "B", "C"],
      y: [0.1, 0.15, 0.20],
      type: "bar",
      name: "series 1c", 
      xaxis: 'x1',
      barmode: 'stack', 
      marker: {color: '#CCF'}
    },
    {
      x: ["A", "B", "C"],
      y: [0.3, 0.35, 0.4],
      type: "bar",
      name: "series 2a",
      xaxis: 'x2',     
      barmode: 'stack', marker: {color: '#080'}
    },
    {
      x: ["A", "B", "C"],
      y: [0.25, 0.15, 0.05],
      type: "bar",
      name: "series 2b",
      xaxis: 'x2',     
      barmode: 'stack', marker: {color: '#8c8'}
    },
    {
      x: ["A", "B", "C"],
      y: [0.45, 0.50, 0.55],
      type: "bar",
      name: "series 2c", 
      xaxis: 'x2',
      barmode: 'stack', marker: {color: '#CFC'}
    },
     {
      x: ["A", "B", "C"],
      y: [0.3, 0.35, 0.4],
      type: "bar",
      name: "series 3a", 
      xaxis: 'x3',
      barmode: 'stack', marker: {color: '#880'}
    },
    {
      x: ["A", "B", "C"],
      y: [0.6, 0.50, 0.40],
      type: "bar",
      name: "series 3b", 
      xaxis: 'x3',
      barmode: 'stack', marker: {color: '#CC8'}
    },
    {
      x: ["A", "B", "C"],
      y: [0.1, 0.15, 0.20],
      type: "bar",
      name: "series 3c", 
      xaxis: 'x3',
      barmode: 'stack', marker: {color: '#FFC'}
    },
  ],
  {
    barmode: "stack",
    yaxis: {tickformat: '%'},
    xaxis: {
      domain: [0, 0.33],
      anchor: 'x1', 
      title: 'Apples'
    },
    xaxis2: {
      domain: [0.33, 0.66],
      anchor: 'x2', title: 'Pears'
    },
    xaxis3: {
      domain: [0.67, 1.0],
      anchor: 'x3', title: 'Cherries'
    }
  }
);
```

Comment: can you attach a snippet of that chart?

Comment: @ZainKhan You can just drop the code into CodePen https://codepen.io/__proto__/pen/XqgWEq

Comment: @ZainKhan Plotly now allows axis type "multicategory" that simplifies this.  I posted a new answer to this question just now.

Comment: pls have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70955021/horizontal-bar-chart-in-react?noredirect=1#comment125435133_70955021

Answer (score 1):

**Newer answer as of 2021**
Plotly.js now allows nested categorical axes without needing to create subplots with dedicated axes (see https://plotly.com/python/categorical-axes/)

[image]

The above chart has

```
Plotly.newPlot(
  "myDiv",
  [
    {
      x: [
        ["Apples","Apples","Apples","Pears","Pears","Pears","Dates","Dates","Dates"],
        ["East", "South","West","East", "South","West","East", "South","West"]
      ],
      y: [0.3, 0.35, 0.4,0.3, 0.35, 0.4,0.3, 0.35, 0.4],
      type: "bar",
      name: "Snack", 
      marker: {color: '#448'}
    },
    {
      x: [
        ["Apples","Apples","Apples","Pears","Pears","Pears","Dates","Dates","Dates"],
        ["East", "South","West","East", "South","West","East", "South","West"]
      ],
      y: [0.6, 0.50, 0.40,0.25, 0.15, 0.05,0.6, 0.50, 0.40],
      type: "bar",
      name: "Ingredient", 
      marker: {color: '#88C'}
    },
    {
      x: [
        ["Apples","Apples","Apples","Pears","Pears","Pears","Dates","Dates","Dates"],
        ["East", "South","West","East", "South","West","East", "South","West"]
      ],
      y: [0.1, 0.15, 0.20,0.45, 0.50, 0.55,0.1, 0.15, 0.20],
      type: "bar",
      name: "Garnish", 
      marker: {color: '#CCF'}
    }
  ],
  {
    barmode: "stack",
    yaxis: {tickformat: '%'},
    xaxis: {
      type: 'multicategory', 
      title: 'Fruit'
    },
    yaxis: {
      type: '', 
      range: [0,1],
      tickformat: "0.0%"
    }
  }
);
```

Comment: it is a 100% stacked bar chart, I don't want it as full.. + I want it in horizontal layout

Comment: please have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70955021/horizontal-bar-chart-in-react?noredirect=1#comment125435133_70955021

Comment: I couldn't find this stuff in the official docs, but it works well! Thanks!