# How to create a bar chart with python/ploty with grouped and stacked bars?

Tags: pandas, bar-chart, stacked-chart, plotly-python

I'm trying to represent data as bar chart with Y = number of cars and bikes stacked, X = months, and grouped by year as explained in this image:
[image: plotly grouped and stacked bar chart]

My data are represented by this pandas Dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

df = pd.DataFrame(data={'month': ['jan', 'feb', 'jan', 'jan', 'jan'], 'year': [2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2020], 'type': ['bike', 'car', 'bike', 'car', 'bike'] })
group = df.groupby(['year', 'month', 'type']).size().reset_index(name='count')
px.bar(group, x='month', y='type', color='type', barmode='stack')
```

With this code I'm able to plot a stacked bar chart per month but how to get a grouped bar chart per year as well?

Comment: have you tried to add the parameter `facet_col='year'` in `px.bar`? sorry can't see the image actually so not sure it fits what you want. and y should be count and not type, no?

Comment: facet_col represent data in subplot, what I would like is to have side by side the stacked bars for year 2019 and 2020 for each month.
It would be more or less like this example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50137757/plotly-js-create-stacked-and-grouped-bar-chart where apples, pears and cherries would be january, february and march ; A and B would be 2019 and 2020 ; seriesn would be my 'type"= car or bike.
Even if this example is quite close to my expectations, I can't succeed doing the same in python...

Comment: It is still subplot but inverse month and year I guess, try `fig = px.bar(group, x='year', y='count', color='type', facet_col='month', barmode='stack')` ?